# If my iCloud storage is full, does Reminders and Contacts still sync?

Tags: icloud

I bought a new Macbook Air and my 5 GB free iCloud account is filling up quickly. Does Reminders and Contacts still sync even if I used up all my iCloud? If yes, what if I add photos to my 100's of task in reminders, will it still sync?

Answer (score 1):

When you use up your available iCloud storage, no new items can be added.  Existing content will continue to sync as long as they do not increase in size and cause you to exceed your allocated storage (this will change slightly in iOS 15).

Your options are to either buy more storage or delete items that you no longer use or need.  [Apple has a support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247) that will help you clear out items you don't need so you can reclaim some space.